# ASP.NET Web API binding method

Tags: wcf-web-api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two methods like this

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = ... //get product
        return product;
    }

    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = ... //get product
        return product;
    }
}
```

When I call url: GET http://localhost/api/product/1 . I want the first method is invoked, not the second method.

 How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need unique URIs. You can modify your route to get this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

);

Now you can access your API like this:

http://localhost/api/product/GetProductById/1

http://localhost/api/product/GetProduct/1

I've written a little [introduction to ASP.NET Web API](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2012/02/16/ASPNET-MVC-4-public-beta-including-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx) which shows some of the differences to WCF Web API.

You can also add a default action, e.g. the one the lists all products so you can do something like this:

```
http://localhost/api/product/  // returns the list without specifying the method
```

and the other one is invoked this way

```
http://localhost/api/product/byid/1  // returns the list without specifying the method
```

What I do is having a ProductsController and a ProductController.
ProductsController is responsible for operations on Collections of T (get all) and ProductController is responsible for operations on T (like getting a specific one).

Comment: This way, it is not REST, it's RPC. I am looking for an attribute, such as [NeverBind]... but they have not existed yet, we can use this attribute to mark a method when we don't want to bind it to a URI.

Comment: When I ask this question, I wonder if I have more than a method which are prefixed by Get, how ASP.NET Web API bind them, and I want it REST way, not RPC alike. I google but no answer

Comment: Thanks you, after reading your blog post carefully I understand it. It is ASP.NET Web API convention, I have to follow it if I want it REST way

Comment: Yes, you can make it "REST style" using the routing.